# entered recovery mode by mistake stuck in boot loop

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop

I have accidentally put my phone into recovery mode, and I cannot exit from it. Rebooting doesn't solve anything, it opens to recovery mode again.
I believe that, it happened since I hold the power button too long and accidentally pressed volume button at the same time.

I have checked a lot but couldn't find how to fix this. Since I haven't backed up my pictures yet, I want to know that if there is a way to exit from this mode without deleting my pictures(data)? I couldn't understand if installing from adb (I don't know what it does) or fastboot to reboot will delete my data? In addition, I haven't been able to install the latest update since my phone didn't have enough memory. Could this situation be related to that? Sorry for asking lot of questions but I am really worried since I don't have any service to have it checked up .

P.S:my volume button is not stuck.

Answer (score -3):

Install adb  & fastboot drivers:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

then plug in your phone and run in the command line

```
fastboot devices
```

*if it says fastboot cannot be found, then change directories until you are in the same directory as fastboot.exe, or add it as an env variable

if you see your device listed, run

```
fastboot reboot
```

that will try to reboot the device normally.

Comment: How the phone can be detected without USB debugging enabled? Can you explain how to make it  detected from the recovery?

Comment: Even more, how is it *supposed* to detect the device at all if it is in recovery mode? Fastboot only works in bootloader mode.

Comment: It can be detected in ADB Sideload mode though. But I'm not sure if the reboot command will work...

Comment: Sorry, boot into bootloader mode. Then run the fastboot commands. You dont need usb debugging to use fastboot in bootloader.